# Apache Storm Remote Topology Submission

Tags: java, apache-storm

I have been testing remote submission of Storm Topologies using IDE (Eclipse). 
And I succeeded uploading simple storm topology to remote Storm cluster, but the weird thing is when I checked Storm UI to make sure whether the topology, which was submitted remotely, is working without problems, I saw just _acker bolt in the UI but other bolts and spout is not there. After that I submitted the topology manually from command line and again checked Storm UI, and it is working as it is supposed to work without problems. I have been looking for the reason but couldn't find. I attached both topology and remote submitter class below and corresponding Storm UI pictures:

> This is the output from Eclipse console (after remote submission)

```
225  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Uploading topology jar     T:\STORM_TOPOLOGIES\Benchmark.jar to assigned location: /app/storm/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-d3ca2e14-c1d4-45e1-b21c-70f62c62cd84.jar
234  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Successfully uploaded topology jar to assigned location: /app/storm/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-d3ca2e14-c1d4-45e1-b21c-70f62c62cd84.jar
```

Here is topology:

```
public class StormBenchmark {


// ******************************************************************************************
public static class GenSpout extends BaseRichSpout {

    //private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(StormBenchmark.class.getName());

    private Long count = 1L;
    private Object msgID;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private static final Character[] CHARS = new Character[] { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h'};
    private static final String[] newsagencies = {"bbc", "cnn", "reuters", "aljazeera", "nytimes", "nbc news", "fox news", "interfax"}; 

    SpoutOutputCollector _collector;
    int _size;
    Random _rand;
    String _id;
    String _val;
    // Constructor
    public GenSpout(int size) {
        _size = size;
    }  

    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
        _rand = new Random();
        _id = randString(5);
        _val = randString2(_size);
    }
    //Business logic
    public void nextTuple() {

        count++;
        msgID = count;
        _collector.emit(new Values(_id, _val), msgID);
    }

    public void ack(Object msgID) {
        this.msgID = msgID;
    }

    private String randString(int size) {

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            buf.append(CHARS[_rand.nextInt(CHARS.length)]);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    private String randString2(int size) {

        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
        for(int i=0; i<size; i++) {
            buf.append(newsagencies[_rand.nextInt(newsagencies.length)]);
        }
        return buf.toString();
    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("id", "item"));
    }        
}
// =======================================================================================================
// =================================== B O L T ===========================================================
public static class IdentityBolt extends BaseBasicBolt {    

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("id", "item"));
    }
    public void execute(Tuple tuple, BasicOutputCollector collector) {

        String character = tuple.getString(0);
        String agency = tuple.getString(1);
        List<String> box = new ArrayList<String>();
        box.add(character);
        box.add(agency);
        try {
            fileWriter(box);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        box.clear();
    } 

    public void fileWriter(List<String> listjon) throws IOException {

        String pathname = "/home/hduser/logOfStormTops/logs.txt";
        File file = new File(pathname);
        if (!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));

        writer.write(listjon.get(0) + " : " + listjon.get(1));
        writer.newLine();
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();         
    }
}


//storm jar storm-benchmark-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-standalone.jar storm.benchmark.ThroughputTest demo 100 8 8 8 10000
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("spout", new GenSpout(8), 2).setNumTasks(4);

    builder.setBolt("bolt", new IdentityBolt(), 4).setNumTasks(8)
            .shuffleGrouping("spout");


    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setMaxSpoutPending(200);
    conf.setStatsSampleRate(0.0001);
    //topology.executor.receive.buffer.size: 8192 #batched
    //topology.executor.send.buffer.size: 8192 #individual messages
    //topology.transfer.buffer.size: 1024 # batched

    conf.put("topology.executor.send.buffer.size", 1024);
    conf.put("topology.transfer.buffer.size", 8);
    conf.put("topology.receiver.buffer.size", 8);
    conf.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_WORKER_CHILDOPTS, "-Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=1%ID%,server=y,suspend=n");

    StormSubmitter.submitTopology("SampleTop", conf,   builder.createTopology());
}
}
```

And here is The RemoteSubmitter class:

```
public class RemoteSubmissionTopo {

@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes", "unused" })
public static void main(String... args) {


    Config conf = new Config();
    TopologyBuilder topoBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();
    conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "117.16.142.49");
    conf.setDebug(true);
    Map stormConf = Utils.readStormConfig();
    stormConf.put("nimbus.host", "117.16.142.49");
    String jar_path = "T:\\STORM_TOPOLOGIES\\Benchmark.jar";


    Client client = NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(stormConf).getClient();

    try {
        NimbusClient nimbus = new NimbusClient(stormConf, "117.16.142.49", 6627);
        String uploadedJarLocation = StormSubmitter.submitJar(stormConf, jar_path);
        String jsonConf = JSONValue.toJSONString(stormConf);

        nimbus.getClient().submitTopology("benchmark-tp", uploadedJarLocation, jsonConf, topoBuilder.createTopology());



    } catch (TTransportException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (AlreadyAliveException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidTopologyException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        Thread.sleep(6000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

And Here is the Storm UI pict (in case of remote submission)

[image]

And Here is the other Storm UI pict (in case of manual submission)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `RemoteSubmissionTopo` you use `TopologyBuilder topoBuilder = new TopologyBuilder();` but do not call `setSpout(...)`/`setBolt(...)`. Thus, you are submitting an topology with no operators...

Btw: `RemoteSubmissionTopo` is actually not required at all. You can use `StormBenchmark` to submit remotely. Just add `conf.put(Config.NIMBUS_HOST, "117.16.142.49");` in `main` and set JVM option `-Dstorm.jar=/path/to/topology.jar` and you are good to run.

Comment: thank you, I thought that spout and bolt were defined in Bechmark.jar's topology class was enough

Comment: If you use `RemoteSubmissionTopo` the main method of `StormBenchmark` is never executed and `RemoteSubmissionTopo` used it's own instance of `TopologyBuilder`. Both classes are completed independent from each other. Thus, it is clear that it cannot work .